# Tomcat - Spring DataSource JNDI not found but it exists

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I've some problem to make work the `JndiDataSourceLookup` with tomcat...
I cloned a tomcat with all it's configuration and applications from a vm to another.
The original installation works fine, but when I tried to start the new one it fails saying:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/sipreDs] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

So I tried to make some debug and write my factory method as:

```
@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public DataSource dataSource(){
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> names = context.list("java:comp/env/jdbc");
    System.out.println("========================================");
    System.out.println("           CONTEXT JNDI");
    System.out.println("========================================");
    while (names.hasMore()){
        NameClassPair name = names.next();
        System.out.println(name.getName());
    }
    System.out.println("=========================================");
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    return dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/sipreDs");
}
```

The output is:

```
========================================
       CONTEXT JNDI
========================================
sipreDs
=========================================
```

The datasource is define in the `conf/context.xml` file:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/sipreDs" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActvive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="sipre" password="sipre" driverClassName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sipre"/>
```

Why it prints the datasource with the normal jndi but using spring throws an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
return (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/sipreDs");
```

It seems that you are using jdbc in the lookup of the context and the datasource

Comment: You mean that the previous code did not work in Spring? I have written code like it many times in Spring 3+ and ran the applications in Tomcat 7 without any problems

Comment: Using the JNDI Context directly it works, Spring does the same but throws the exception...and furthermore previously, before I copied the tomcat installation that code with that installation works...

Comment: SOLVED! It works, the problem was the mysql user, I forgot to create it, but the Spring exception was confusing me...Thank you!